# jQuery: How to add div class "selected" on image click?

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="result">
    <div class="bigCover">
        <a href="http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018001/">
            <img src= "img/cat_noCover.gif" alt= "HTML5: The Missing Manual, First Edition" class="book">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cover">
        <img src="img/bkt_noCover.gif" class="book">
    </div>
</div>
```

When i click on the image i would like to add the class selected to the div with class result.
But i can't get it to work using jQuery.

i got this as jQuery code now after trying some things.

```
$("img").click(function() 
{
    $(this).parent().addClass( "selected" );
});​
```

It works/starts on document.ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$("img").click(function() //$("img .book").click(function() more accurate selector
{
    $('.result').addClass("selected");
});​
```

if you have more then one element with class `result` then you can target it more accurate using:

```
$("img").click(function() //$("img .book").click(function() more accurate selector
{
    $(this).parent().prev('.result').addClass( "selected" );
});​
```

Comment: although it will work with given example, you can probably suppose the page will contain more than 1 div with that class... and your answer would fail in that case.

Comment: It does add the class to the image. How ever i have multiple images with the same class result. It should only add the new class to the specific image i click on.

Comment: @user3641047 can use the selector which i have give in commented code  $("img .book")

Comment: @bartdude i forgot to add a class in between. The image i click on is in the cover class. How ever in between the div result and the cover class is bigcover. If i do previous i need to "skip" the big cover.

Comment: @user3641047 for that you can use the second solution in my ans$(this).parent().prev('.result').addClass( "selected" );

Comment: @SomnathKharat I only got it to work adding a class to big cover (by using $(this).parent().prev().addClass( "selected" ); but if i add .prev(".result") i doesnt do anything (got no error either) Thanks for the help and quick responses tho :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(this).parent().prev().addClass( "selected" );
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D96fn/)**

Comment: I don't understand the downvote cause that's how I would have done it so... upvote for me :-)

Comment: @Bartdude: that was my fault. earlier i didnt saw `.result` getting close and provided the solution `$(this).parents('.result').addClass( "selected" );`  :P

Comment: Oh ok, didn't see the edit. My bad then, but the upvote is still valid :-)